# Dynamic DNS NAT for IPv4 and AAAA for IPv6 - is it possible?

Tags: dns, ipv6, nat, dynamic-dns

I have a router named **alice**, and servers named **bob** and **charlie**. I want to be able to use IPv6 to go directly to **alice**, **bob**, or **charlie**, and I want IPv4 to continue to work, giving me **alice**'s address so that it can use NAT to get to **bob** and **charlie**. Also, I have dynamic DNS.

So currently I have:

```
CNAME alice -> abcdef.dyndnsroutercompany.com
CNAME bob -> alice
CNAME charlie -> alice
```

now I want to add AAAA records for **alice**, **bob**, and **charlie**, but I can't, because they would conflict with the CNAME records. I can't even convert all the CNAME records to A records, because they are assigned dynamically by a third party.

Is there any DNS solution to this problem?

Currently my solution is to abandon IPv4 completely.

Comment: What's stopping you from selecting a DDNS provider that does what you need (it might be out there!) or even implementing one yourself? It's not trivial, but it's not hard either.

Comment: See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/198884/18736), but it's perhaps not a good solution.

Comment: @DanielB I've implemented my own before, yes, it's not very hard. But I believe my question still stands.

Comment: @harrymc That seems to be exactly replicating my question. Perhaps I should close this one as a dupe of that one.

Comment: It's not on our site, so it's not a duplicate. Just wanted to know if you would think it a solution.

Comment: @harrymc well if someone copies and pastes that answer i will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This subject was treated in the ServerFault article of
[IPv6 AAAA vs. CNAME for same domain name](https://serverfault.com/questions/198877/ipv6-aaaa-vs-cname-for-same-domain-name/198884#198884).

The accepted
[answer by adamo](https://serverfault.com/a/198884/18736)
is quoted here :

> I copy from DNS for [Rocket Scientists](http://zytrax.com/books/dns/):
>
> > CNAME RRs cannot have any other RRs
> > with the same name, for example, a TXT
> >
> > - well that was true until DNSSEC came along and in this case RRSIG, NSEC and
> >   certain KEY RRs can now occupy the
> >   same name.
>
> Therefore what you want to do cannot be done using a CNAME.  Use the
> CNAME to access your homesite via IPv4 and have a myhomesite-v6 AAAA
> record point to the IPv6 address
>
> If you do not want such a solution, you have to implement a mechanism
> that updates your DNS zone each time your IP address changes with:
>
> ```
> myhomesite IN A IPv4.add.ress
>            IN AAAA IPv6.add.ress
> ```
>
> But that depends on the API (if any) that your DNS provider exports to
> you.  For example if I had root access on the DNS server, I would
> periodically `host -t a example.dyndns.org` and use the output to
> update the zonefile with the IPv4 address for myhomesite.